# PHP json_encode & SQL server callback function returns only one result

Tags: php, sql, json, foreach, callback

I'm trying to set up a PHP callback function for use in our application. It needs to pull data from a SQL server, and while I can get it to work initially, it's not quite doing what I want.

**Code:**

```
//Callback function for passing queries

function queryCallback($conn, $query) {
  $response = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($response)){
    if ($row === false) {
       die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $responseData[] = $row;
  }
  foreach($responseData as $v) {
    $output[key($v)] = current($v);
  }
  $responseDataJSON = JSON_encode($output, 128);
  return $responseDataJSON;
}
```

In the above, $conn represents our server creds, as passed to sqlsrv_connect(), and $query is the string containing the query passed to SQL. Both have been verified as working.

**Issue:**

This code contacts the server correctly, and runs the query, but it only returns one result. This is obviously a problem with how the loops are set up, but I just can't spot it

Comment: Is the "one result" always the last row? `$output[key($v)] = current($v);` doesn't look right to me at all, Can you explain this construct and why you perform this action? What happens if you simply did `JSON_encode($responseData,128);` and skipped that additional loop?

Comment: Your code reads to me "for each row, get the only the first column and set it to `$output['firstcolumnname']` overwriting the existing set value.

Comment: That is there in an attempt to resolve an issue I was having with JSON_encode() returning duplicates of every returned value from SQL. without it, I get objects back that look like this: (3303) [{…}, {…},…]
[0 … 99]
0:{0: "Person's name here", "": "Person's name here again"}. Also, the one returned result is always the first in the table

Comment: The problem won't be with `json_encode()` but with the data you feed it. Focus on `$output[key($v)]`, this code isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: I agree with this, I need to take another look at my query

Comment: It would help if you showed the result of the query and the structure of the JSON you're trying to return from it.

Comment: What you probably want is `$output[$v['col1']] = $v['col2']`

Comment: You also don't need two loops. You can fill in `$output` in the loop that fetches from the DB.

Comment: With help from scuzzy, I figured this out late today. I will write up an explanation of what was ACTUALLY wrong in the morning, for archival purposes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling is that the following `$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($response)` is fetching the whole row as an array, but your usage of `$output[key($v)] = current($v)` is only returning the first column with the same key, and overwriting the $output index with every iteration.

```
foreach($responseData as $v) {
  $output[key($v)] = current($v);
}
```

lets say you instead perform

```
foreach($responseData as $k => $v) {
  $output[$k] = $v;
}
```

At which point this is redundant as `$responseData[]` already is this structure.

You may actually want this if you plan to extract just the first column out of your row.

```
foreach($responseData as $v) {
  $output[] = current($v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really good explanation :) It looks like I need to rethink the query I'm passing and figure out a way around the duplicates that it's creating.